# What control events start and end highlight state of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I am creating piano-like view with `UIButton` as piano keys. What `UIControlEvents` should I listen for to get callbacks when button gets and loses highlighted state?

I tried to make subclass of `UIButton` and add property observer for `highlighted` and it was working fine. However sometimes I need to set highlighted state manually from code and that really messes it up as there is no way to tell whether event was user or app initiated.

Comment: Do you think you will get any callback to even listen to `AllEvents` when modified highlighted state from code?

Comment: If I understand your problem right I think you should use UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlEventTouchUpOutside event

Comment: Maybe use a `boolean` as an on/off toggle to keep track of the state...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To mimic piano key behavior I used the following `UIControlEvents`:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: "pressed", forControlEvents: [.touchDown])
self.addTarget(self, action: "released", forControlEvents: [.touchDragExit, .touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside, .touchCancel])
```

Comment: You may also want `touchDragEnter` to trigger `pressed`

Comment: You also probably don't need `touchUpOutside` since it necessarily happens after `touchDragExit`

Answer (score 2):

gets highlighted state:`UIControlEventTouchDown`

lose highlighted state:`UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`